# Module not found. Trying to implement a Linked List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to implement a LinkedList from a tutorial I got, but I keep getting this error I don't know where I am getting it wrong because I followed exactly what they did in the tutorial.

##LinkedList

```
from LinkedListDS.Node import Node;

class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None;
        self.counter = 0;
    #O(N)
    def traverseList(self):
        actualNode = self.head;

        while actualNode is not None:
            print("%d " % actualNode.data);
            actualNode = actualNode.nextNode;
    #O(1)
    def insertStart(self, data):

        self.counter += 1;

        newNode = Node(data);

        if not self.head:
            self.head = newNode;
        else:
            newNode.NextNode = self.head;
            self.head = newNode;
    #O(1) instead of O(N)
    def size(self):
        return self.counter;

    #O(N) !!!
    def insertEnd(self, data):

        if self.head is None:
            self.insertStart(data);
            return;
        self.counter +=1;

        newNode = Node(data);
        actualNode = self.head;

        while actualNode.nextNode is not None:
            actualNode.nextNode = newNode;
        actualNode.nextNode = newNode;

    def remove(self,data):
        self.counter -=1;

        if self.head:
            if data == self.head.data:
                self.head = self.head.nextNode;
            else:
                self.head.remove(data, self.head);
```

#Node

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data;
        self.nextNode = Node;

    def remove(self, data, previousNode):
        if self.data == data:
            previousNode.nextNode = self.nextNode;
            del self.data;
            del self.nextNode;
        else:
            if self.nextNode is not None:
                self.nextNode.remove(data, self);
```

ERROR

```
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\Python tut\python> & C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/.../Documents/Python tut/python/LinkedListDS/LinkedList.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gbles\Documents\Python tut\python\LinkedListDS\LinkedList.py", line 1, in <module>
    from LinkedListDS.Node import Node;
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LinkedListDS'
```

I was expecting it to run with the traversed output and removed inputs

##Simple Application

```
from LinkedListDS.LinkedList import LinkedList;

linkedList = LinkedList();

linkedList.insertEnd(12);
linkedList.insertEnd(122);
linkedList.insertEnd(3);
linkedList.insertEnd(31);

linkedList.traverseList();

linkedList.remove(12);
 
linkedList.traverseList();
```

Comment: Do you have a file named LinkedListDS.py? That's what Python is looking for.

Comment: PS: You don't need to put `;` at the end of lines in Python.

Comment: Can you add a mark-up for this directory? It seems like python is looking for a module (a directory with a \_\_init\_\_.py file) named 'LinkedListDS' that has a file named 'Node.py' in it. Then file Node.py should have a class named, 'Node' in it.

Comment: Note that linked lists are simpler to implement when `self.head` is guaranteed not to be `None`. Let `self.head = Node(0)` be a dummy node, with `self.head.next` the actual first node of the list. `self.head.next is None` indicates an empty list, and the data in the dummy node can be any arbitrary data you might want to store. In particular, you longer need multiple `insert` methods. `insert` *always* inserts a node after another node, so inserting at the beginning of the list just means inserting after the dummy node.

Comment: Problem still not solved